# Call to a member function toArray() on array error in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

I have 2 postgres queries which fetch data from the database based on certain criteria
Example :The first query returns the following value (the value is saved in $templates)

```
Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [name] => 1 [id] => 352 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [name] => 2 [id] => 438 )
        [2] => Array ( [name] => 3 [id] => 442 ) 
      )
```

The second query returns the following values (value saved in $selectedtemplates)

```
Array 
        ( 
          [0] => Array ( [form_template_id] => 352 )
          [1] => Array ( [form_template_id] => 438 )
        )
```

Then a function to check the 2 queries if the id value matches and a variable selected is set as true

```
$nutemplates = array_map(function($template){
                    return $template->toArray([], ["selected"]);
                }, $templates);
                foreach($selectedTemplates as $selectedTemplate) {
                    foreach($nutemplates as $idx => $template) {
                        if($selectedTemplate->form_template_id == $template["id"])
                        {
                            $nutemplates[$idx]["selected"] = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But I am getting the following error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toArray() on array
```

Comment: This means, that the `$template` is not an object, but You are trying to call a method on it.

Comment: `$template` is already an array

Comment: Why not do that in SQL?